# ThreadJob module stopped working for seemingly no reason

Tags: multithreading, powershell

I'm on Powershell 5.1 which IIRC supports ThreadJob OOB.
I have a script which uses the module which used to work without issues.
Now I'm getting the following error:

```
ForEach-Object : The term 'Start-ThreadJob' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
```

Admittedly I haven't run the script (or used ThreadJob) in a while, but I get the "not recognized" error even when I just call `Start-ThreadJob` from the terminal.
I've rebooted and run DISM and sfc which didn't find any issues.

This is on a fairly fresh Windows 10 install.

Am I forgetting something?
I vaguely recall experiencing something like this a long time ago, but don't remember how I got around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Windows PowerShell*** - the legacy, Windows-only, ships-with-Windows edition of PowerShell whose latest and last version is 5.1.x - **does *not* come with** the [`ThreadJob` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_thread_jobs) that provides **the [`Start-ThreadJob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/threadjob/start-threadjob) cmdlet** - only the modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand **[PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (v6+) does**.

However, **you can install the module *on demand* in Windows PowerShell**, from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob/), with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser ThreadJob`, for instance.

The following **cross-edition idiom** installs the module on demand when running in Windows PowerShell, in the scope of the current user:

```bash
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt 6 -and -not (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore -Type Cmdlet Start-ThreadJob)) {
  Write-Verbose "Installing module 'ThreadJob' on demand..."
  Install-Module -ErrorAction Stop -Scope CurrentUser ThreadJob
}

# Getting here means that Start-ThreadJob is now available.
Get-Command -Type Cmdlet Start-ThreadJob
```